# Freelance for moderately complex admin support

Tags: untagged

Mailing lists and question/answers works great for problems that are independently encountered by several people. But sometimes we (as in experienced amateurs) run into problems that aren't so common, nobody has blogged about it and experts advice not readily available. 
For IT-admin related stuff can someone please recommend how can  amateurs pay experts and get hands on advice.

The kinds of problems I am talking about are like 
setting up nxserver or openvpn on freeBSD box. The install/config is not so simple, the documentation not easy for non-it professionals. Therefore getting step by step advice would be quite helpful.

Comment: Did you have a question?

Comment: This question is off-topic under current topicality rules.

Answer (score 2):

Find someone good (that's the tricky bit) and keep them on retainer to help you on an as-needed basis.

How to find that someone good is hard, and you'll probably have to kiss a lot of frogs, but the nice thing is that you've got a lot of good sources of research for anyone you're looking at hiring (or if you decide you want to approach someone cold) -- all their previous history on the Internet, answering questions, asking questions, blog posts, etc.  These can give you an excellent insight into what a person knows and how they go about explaining things and working on problems.

Answer (score 0):

The freelance markets out there should be a good starting point.

State your case clearly and stick to one of the available sites; account reputation, paperwork, general comfort... unfortunately many of these sites are on the low-end of usability and simplicity.

[rentacoder.com](http://ttp://www.rentacoder.com/RentACoder/SmallBiz.asp?txtFromURL=AId_1362184) and [guru.com](http://www.guru.com) are two places where you **may** find freelance assistance